# ajax(search suggest) funny character problem

Tags: ajax, unicode, character-encoding, asp-classic

ajax(search suggest), if input funny character(like Ô) and submit it, "?" is displayed in *****.asp. ( response.write (request.form("str")))

i am using

```
xmlhttp.open("post", "*****.asp", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
xmlhttp.send("str="+escape($("str").value));
```

and there is `<%@CODEPAGE=65001%>` in `*****.asp` file

How can i get the correct word--- "Ô" in `*****.asp`

Comment: this problem is on the function escape().  funny character(Ô) is encoded

Answer (score 0):

escape() is terrible, avoid it at all costs. Try this:

```
xmlhttp.send("str="+encodeURIComponent($("str").value));
```

This would encode Ô into %C3%94 - assuming the page decoding it supports utf8 you should be fine.